# Plotting results of DBSCAN in Julia

Tags: julia

Write a function that takes the DBSCAN result and the data as inputs, and generates a scatter plot, with each cluster's points shown in different colour, and the noise data points in black.

I have no idea how to plot this! Can someone please help I have the following.

```
 # function for plotting DBSCAN results - tbd
function plot_dbscan_result(db_res, X)
    p = plot()  # start an empty plot
    # plot out data points depending on their membership/assignments
    p # bring up the plot for display
end

plot_dbscan_result(db_res, X)






centers = [[1, 1] [-1, -1] [1, -1]]
X = make_blobs(centers, 200)
scatter(X[1,:], X[2,:], label="")

db_res = dbscan(dists, 0.2, 30);
```

Comment: You are likely to get much better help if you can add a *small* sample of `db_res` and `X`.